# Flattening arrays in CoffeeScript

Tags: arrays, coffeescript, flatten

How does one go about flattening a nested multidimension array in CoffeeScript?
I'd like to go from

```
A = [1, [1,2] , [1,[1,[1,2],3],2] , 3]
```

to

```
B = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this without a loop?

What I have now is:

```
flatten = (array) ->
  flat = []
  for element in array
    if Array.isArray(element)
      flat = flat.concat flatten element
    else
      flat.push element
  flat
```

Comment: pls define "efficient"

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce` method to make recursive solution like following.

```
flat = (r, a) ->
  if (Array.isArray(a))
      return a.reduce(flat, r)

  r.push(a)
  return r

array = [1, [1,2] , [1,[1,[1,2,[10, 11, [23, 34, [100]]]],3],2] , 3]
console.log array.reduce(flat, []) # [ 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 11, 23, 34, 100, 3, 2, 3 ]
```

I am not sure whether it is efficient or not, it just another way to solve your problem. Hope it will help someone.